# Proper way to scale out build agents on a VM for VS Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

What's the best practice for scaling out VSTS build agents on a single VM?

I've read through [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/admin/index) and [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows), but I'm still not sure how to do it correctly.

I'm thinking maybe a folder called c:\builds. Then extract the agent bits to a folder under that for each agent (i.e. c:\builds\1 or c:\builds\agent01). Not sure about that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register multiple agents using whatever directory scheme your heart desires. On Windows, shorter paths are better because of the maddening legacy 260 character limit on file paths.

Also keep in mind that builds are typically I/O limited. Putting multiple agents on the same physical hard drive isn't going to get you too much unless you're using SSDs. I wouldn't bother with more than 2 agents per disk, although your mileage may vary depending on disk speed, memory, etc. It's something worth profiling. Past a certain point, your builds will actually run slower, but in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Only two agents will live on this box, so I just went with c:\agent\1 and c:\agent\2.